# How to fix: "Status: GracePeriod Blueprint Missing dependencies: (&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)"

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I built a bundle using camel-archetype-blueprint.
 But after deploy to ServiceMix, it has not run and stayed in GracePeriod state.
 There is no errors in log:display.
 Calling bundle:diag results in:
 "Status: GracePeriod Blueprint Missing dependencies: 
 (&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint))".

```
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
     https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint 
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
     http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 
     http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd">

<cm:property-placeholder
    persistent-id="HelloBean" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="greeting" value="Hi from Camel" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="MyRouteBuilder" class="com.bpjava.tfsredmine.MyRouteBuilder" />

<camelContext id="blueprint-bean-context"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <routeBuilder ref="MyRouteBuilder" />
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Did you try to let it run for 5-10 minutes? I had similar issue due to a bug in Camel 2.16. My bundles were just long to start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install camel-blueprint feature on your container

Comment: This feature has been installed:  40 | Active      |  50 | 2.16.5   | camel-blueprint
 What else could be wrong?

Comment: which SMX version? Check if you have aries-blueprint feature installed.

Comment: Version 7.0.1. aries-blueprint    | 4.0.9    | x  | Started | standard-4.0.9   | Aries Blueprint